# AWS CloudWatch sending logs but not custom metrics to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

first time asker.

So I've been trying to implement AWS Cloud Watch to monitor Disk Usage on an EC2 instance running EC2 Linux. I'm interesting in doing this just using the CW Agent and I've installed it according to the how-to found [here](https://marbot.io/blog/monitoring-ec2-disk-usage.html). The install runs fine and I've made sure I've created an IAM Role for the instance as is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent.html). Unfortunately whenever I run the amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service it only sends log files and not the custom used_percent measurement specified. I receive this error when I tail the logs.

```
2021-06-18T15:41:37Z E! WriteToCloudWatch failure, err:  RequestError: send request failed
```

caused by: Post "https://monitoring.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 172.17.1.25:443: i/o timeout

I've done my best googlefu but gotten nowhere thus far. If you've got any advice it would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This looks like a network error, can you check your outbound security groups rules? You will need to have outbound on TCP 443 (0.0.0.0/0). Also, what region is your instance in? It could that you are using the wrong region, the endpoint you are using is US West 2 (Oregon)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Outbound rules are Port Range & Protocol set to All, destination 0.0.0.0/0 My instance is in US-West-2

Comment: Further Comment: I've got no idea where the 172.17.1.25 machine is coming from, its not one I've setup or a destination I've directed the CW agent to send anything. If you've got any insights I'd appreciate it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, please check if your instances have internet access, and if VPC Hostname is enabled in the VPC panel. Another thing to check would be the routes, there should be a "0.0.0.0/0" route pointing to either a NAT Gateway or Internet Gateway

Answer (score 1):

Belated answer to my own question. I had to create a security group that would accept traffic from that same security group!

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, it definitely wasn't a network restriction as I was still able to telnet to the monitoring endpoint.

From AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent.html

> One role or user enables CloudWatch agent to be installed on a server
> and send metrics to CloudWatch. The other role or user is needed to
> store your CloudWatch agent configuration in Systems Manager Parameter
> Store. Parameter Store enables multiple servers to use one CloudWatch
> agent configuration.

If you're using the default cloudwatchagent configuration wizard, you may require extra policy  **CloudWatchAgentAdminRole** in your role for the agent to connect to the monitoring service.